# Why does the := operator behave differently with different constructions?

Tags: r, syntax, data.table, operator-keyword

I'm trying to use the := operator in r to assign a variable whose name I provide within a function.
To keep the code readable when assigning multiple variables, I would like to use the `:=`(paste0("var",i)=3) construct.  But it seems to behave differently from the paste0("var",i):=3 construct.

Is this expected behavior of := or am I missing something? 
Is there something I can do to make the `:=` construct work?

Example:

```
dt<-data.table(var1=1:10)
#This works fine:
dt[,paste0("var",1):=3]
#But this throws an error:
dt[,`:=`(paste0("var",1)=3)]
Error: unexpected '=' in "dt[,`:=`(paste0("var",1)="
```

Comment: r u looking for `dt[,`:=`(paste0("var",1), 3)]`

Comment: Wow! That works!  Thank you! Now I'm extra confused!  What's it doing? What would be the syntax for multiple variables?

Comment: u can see `help(":=")` and work thr the egs

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a `data.table` problem but an R one:

```
list(paste0('var', 1) = 3)
```

> Error: unexpected '=' in "list(paste0('var', 1) ="

To construct the names like this, use `:=` as an infix operator:

```
dt[ , paste0('var', 1) := 3]
```

Comment: Alternately and less readably `dt[,\`:=\`(paste0("var",1), 3)]` which is possible with any infix operator, eg `\`+\`(1,2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 3 ways to look at this. The first 2 ways come from `help(":=")`

1) LHS := RHS form

```
# DT[i, LHS := RHS, by = \dots]
# DT[i, c("LHS1", "LHS2") := list(RHS1, RHS2), by = \dots]
```

2) Functional form

```
# DT[i, `:=`(LHS1 = RHS1,
#            LHS2 = RHS2,
#            \dots), by = \dots]
```

Here `LHS` can be a something that eval to a character vector but `LHS1` and `LHS2` are already single length character.

3) The 3rd way is treating `:=` as a binary operator function and hence `dt[,`:=`(paste0("var",1), 3)]` works as well.

In R, you cannot call a function with the argument name to be evaluated on the fly (without delving into non-standard evaluation). For example,

```
f <- function(x1) x1
f(paste0("x", 1)=3)
```

> Error: unexpected '=' in "    f(paste0("x", 1)="

---

examples to address OP's comments:

```
dt[, c(paste0("var", 1), "var2") := .(1, 2)]

dt[, `:=`(var3=3, var4=4)]

val <- c(var5=5, var6=6)
for (x in paste0("var", 5:6))
    set(dt, j=x, value=val[x])
```

Comment: Thank you.  It does seem overall that the code construct I was hoping to use isn't going to work.  So I'll go a different route.  I guess I can get close enough with chaining, as in: `dt[,paste0("var",1):=1][,paste0("var",2):="Hello"]` etc.